# Getting a Sub to identify if a radiobutton is checked based on a name generated in VB

Tags: vb.net

So I'm creating a Sub to resolve some of my if/elseif statements and shorten my code, and I'm having some trouble with a particular part.

So I call the Sub,

```
Public Sub features(ByRef name As Object, ByRef scode As String, ByRef required As Integer)
```

And I have 3 radiobuttons
pproximity1, 
pproximity2,
pproximity3.

I want to check if pproximity 1, 2, or 3 are checked to output correctly, so

```
If (yvalue.Checked) Then
```

But this throws an error because in Visual Basic it doesn't like when you use a string to name an object

yvalue is created using

```
Dim yvalue As Object = name + "1"
```

So how should I make 
    function(pproximity, PX, 1) 
find which of the 3 radiobuttons are .Clicked = True

Keep in mind, "name" needs to remain the same so that I can use this.

I'm kind of a noob, so explain like you would to a 2 year old.

P.S. I'm using VB 2008

Thanks! JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming **WinForms**, and that your `features()` Sub is located within the Form that contains the RadioButtons, use the [Controls.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) function to **search** for the control with the matching name.  If one is found, **cast** it from Control to a RadioButton:

```
Public Sub features(ByVal name As String, ByVal scode As String, ByVal required As Integer)
    For i As Integer = 1 To 3
        Dim ctl As Control = Me.Controls.Find(name & i, True).FirstOrDefault
        If Not IsNothing(ctl) AndAlso TypeOf ctl Is RadioButton Then
            Dim rb As RadioButton = DirectCast(ctl, RadioButton)
            If rb.Checked Then
                ' ... do something with "rb" ...
                Console.WriteLine("Checked: " & rb.Name)

                ' Exit Sub ' <-- when you find the one that is checked, do you want to stop the sub?
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: How would I go about letting it identify which radiobutton of the three was checked?

Comment: The `rb` variable will be a reference to the RadioButton.  You can get its name with `rb.Name`.